# Download language for text to speech from my app

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have implemented the TTS support for reading the Text Strings in my Application, and that works just fine. The TTS will speak out if the button in my app have pressed. But that i want is when the language is not install from the user's phone, it will install it automatically. How can i do it?

Here's my code

```
buttonTTS = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonTTS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Locale bhs = new Locale("ind-IDN");
            int result = tts.setLanguage(bhs);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "Bahasa tidak didukung");
                // WHAT TO DO WHEN LANGUAGE IS NOT INSTALLED
            } else {
                speakOut();
            }
        }
    });
```

Anyone any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an intent **action - ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA** starting this intent will automatically download required data.

```
  Intent installIntent = new Intent();
        installIntent.setAction(
            TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
        startActivity(installIntent);
```

You can also check if the language exists or not. This is the first step you have to do.

```
    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

You can do it like this. Thankyou i hope this was helpful.

Comment: Let's say that my default language is "en-US". How do I get the TTS engine to install the data for "ind-IDN" as in the OPs example?